# flutter auth ui login with facebook error

Tags: flutter, facebook

I have a problem to login with facebook in flutter
I am using the `firebase_ui_auth` pub to try login with facebook but failed. But after I login to facebook, it show the error message

```
Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Go Back
```

The other login method (email, google, and phone) are well, only facebook is error.

```
FirebaseUIAuth.configureProviders([
      EmailAuthProvider(),
      PhoneAuthProvider(),
      GoogleProvider(clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
      FacebookProvider(clientId: 'app_id'),
    ]);
```

I have copied the app_id, app_secret_id from facebook to fireback. And copied Oauth_redirect_line from firebase to facebook

**firebase_console**
[image: firebase]

**facebook_console**
[image]
[image]

Also, I have tried to clear cookies but still not work